# How to find different chapters of a book/report on internet

Tags: google-chrome, internet, pdf, search

There is a PDF file on a site and it is titled as "Chapter 2:....." which means there are several other chapters, it can be a book or a report with many chapters, I don't know the title of the book/report, the site is huge, through Chrome (by putting slash "/" after the folder name) I cannot get the listing of the folder in which the PDF file is located (http:.../folder name/), is there any simple method or search tricks to find other chapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to search via google with specific search parameters.

Here is an overview:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

You could search like : site:www.test.de filetype:pdf

Comment: Thanx @Ivan, your approach worked, I think I have got all the chapters :)

Comment: I typed for "chapter" then "filetype:pdf" and then "site:......"

Comment: for site address I typed till last sub folder

Answer (score -1):

There are various possibilities here.

1. Chapter 2 might be the name of the book/report. (Most probably not)
2. Try copying some content and pasting it in the google search bar and the       results should give the name of the book.